# Vim using the wrong spell file?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I've been using vim for a long time, but recently I built a new server, and when I opened vim, I found it wasn't using my spell file.

Historically vim would load `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` as it's spell file, but when I tried adding a word to the dictionary, it added it to `en.latin1.add` instead.

```
ls ~/.vim/spell
en.latin1.add  en.latin1.add.spl  en.utf-8.add
```

So as a possible fix, I put `set spelllang=en.utf-8` into my vimrc. But instead of then trying to use `en.utf-8.add`, it used `en.utf-8.latin1.add`. How do I turn that latin1 into a utf-8?

Also as a side note, here are my environment variables:

```
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_ALL=""
declare -x LC_COLLATE="C"
declare -x LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation ([`:help spell-load`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html#spell-load)):

```
Vim searches for spell files in the "spell" subdirectory of the directories in
'runtimepath'.  The name is: LL.EEE.spl, where:
    LL  the language name
    EEE the value of 'encoding'
...
...
...
Exceptions:
- Vim uses "latin1" when 'encoding' is "iso-8859-15".  The euro sign doesn't
  matter for spelling.
```

Despite your environment variables all listing UTF-8, it looks as though Vim's `encoding` is set to either "latin1" or "iso-8859-15". Perhaps you could set Vim's encoding manually by running `:set encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: Sadly changing the encoding still doesn't fix the issue.